# Copying SharePoint DB to a new SharePoint 2010 server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

we would like to know what is the best and easy way to configure a new SharePoint 2010 Server, we have backup the existing DB of SharePoint 2007 (up and running). We would like to mirror the same settings and content of our current SharePoint setup to the new server using the SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question that I don't think can be answered easily here. Check out the 2010 upgrade/migration site to get your high level questions answered and upgrade approach started, then come back here with specific questions.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee517214.aspx

Answer (score 1):

At my company, our shortest path so far with a similar setup (I think) is to copy the Content Database, upgrade it, and then connect it to your SharePoint 2010 Site Collection.

1. Backup your content DB.
2. Restore a copy of the content DB to your SharePoint 2010 SQL ContentDB Server.
3. Create a Web Application in SharePoint 2010 using a temporary content db name.
4. Remove the temp content DB from the 2010 web app.
5. Run the command "stsadm -o addcontentdb -url your.url.here -databasename your_content_db_name"

No need to connect the content db - addcontentdb both upgrades the database and connects it to the web app upon success.

The above steps presume you have run and passed a preupgrade check. - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789638(office.12).aspx

Be sure you are familiar with the info from the sites the other responders have given, it will make a difference in your success.

Answer (score 0):

Hey LJe and MattB, I saw this product promoted in a video on youtube. Can't remember the video, it was a guy driving but he recommended this product for migration. http://www.metalogix.net/Products/SharePoint-Site-Migration-Manager-2010/